# .each loop is not working along with .sort in html

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, each

My following code is working fine for alphabetical sorting of the all `select` tag item.

```
$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1
 }))
```

But I want to apply this sorting for every `select` item separately. for this purpose I am using ".each" loop but it is not working along with .sort. I am using .each as following:

```
$("select").html($("option").each(.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1
 })))
```

Kindly answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to iterate here? Do you want to sort the option elements and iterate over each?

Comment: @RGraham I want to sort every "Select Tag" item albhabetically

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("select").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($("option", $this).sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1 
    }))
});
```

You example doesn't work because you looping through each option instead of each select, and sort not chained to anything.

Comment: This answer has the same problems pointed out with my initial answer.  The $(".option") selector is going to pull every option on the page instead of scoping it to the current select.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `.each` on your select elements and then get each select's child `option` elements, sort them and assign them to the select elements again.

```
$("select").each(function(idx, el) {
  $(el).html( $(el).children("option").sort(your_sort) );
});
```

Comment: @Tomalak: alright, I thought jQuery was smart enough to pass enhanced objects into the function.

Comment: Now you can drop the `idx, el` arguments and use `this` right-away, like it is meant to be. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the HTML of the `<select>` element. Just re-arrange the existing `<option>` elements.

```
function byTextCaseInsensitive(a, b) {
    var ta = a.text.toUpperCase(),
        tb = b.text.toUpperCase();
    return ta === tb ? 0 : ta < tb ? -1 : 1;
}

$("select").each(function () {
    $(this).find("option").sort(byTextCaseInsensitive).appendTo(this);
});
```

Hint: *Appending* an existing node inside an HTML DOM moves it from its previous location.

Answer (score 0):

Your .sort is not chained to anything, it is just sitting on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is off, the `each` method accepts a function to perform on each element in the selected set of elements.  Try surrounding the sorting code with a function and supplying to `each`:

```
$("select").each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).children("option").sort(function (a, b) {
         return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1
     }));    
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MwDQz/

Comment: Won't this just iterate each option and "sort" it, leaving all options in the same order as they were originally?

Comment: @RGraham Yep, I missed that.  Sorry just woke up

Comment: @KevinBowersox I have tried your code but still its not working.I want to apply sorting on every select tag separately but its marching all select items together.

Comment: @KevinBowersox againg im having same problem. Select items are sorted.but its marching all select items together in a drop down. :(

Comment: Updated with fiddle.  The compare function is sorting in descending is that intended?